# Where is the Ionic/Cordova dataDirectory folder?

Tags: file, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm building an Ionic app using the **Ionic Native File** plugin. I need the app to be able to read a file that I've saved in the app itself, but I don't understand where I need to store the file. The official Cordova documentation says something about a certain `cordova.file.dataDirectory`, whereas the Ionic documentation uses this example:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private file: File) { }

...

this.file.checkDir(this.file.dataDirectory, 'mydir').then( //stuff).catch( //stuff);
```

I don't understand where I need to put my file so that the app can read them.

Comment: Which kind of file you have? its DB or any other file ?

Comment: @CodeChanger it's a JSON file

Comment: The answer to your question will depend on the platform you're working with... [The docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#file-system-layouts) on the different file system layouts might be a good starting point.

Comment: I read the docs but still, I'm not able to understand exactly *where* I can store files. The docs speak about a `file:///android_asset/` path, where can I find it?

Comment: @FrancoScarpa this is late, but if you haven't solved it yet, let's do it now. Are the files to be read local to your app or downloaded from a remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use file:///android_asset/

You can store the file in file.dataDirectory

**Storing the file**

I am using http to download a zip. I then unzip and delete the zipped file afterwards.

```
const down = this.http.downloadFile(uri, {}, {}, path + 'data.zip')
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log("DOWNLOAD SUCCESS");
    this.desc = "Extracting";
    this.loading = 100;
    this.downloading = false;

    this.zip.unzip(path + 'data.zip', path, (this.UnzipProgress))
      .then((result) => {
        if(result === 0) this.file.removeFile(path,'data.zip');
        if(result === -1) console.log('UNZIP FAILED');
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("ERROR::");
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);
  });
```

**Retrieving the file**

The only thing that worked for me was `convertFileSrc()`

```
let win: any = window;
let safeURL = win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(this.file.dataDirectory+'data/yourFile.png');
```

Hope this helps